# Query to find foreign keys on database schema

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship

I have two questions i need help with:

1. I would like to have a query that displays foreign key relationships on tables in a schema. My whole goal is to find out if tables in a schema have foreign keys declared to establish relationships between the tables in the schema. For example, using "show crate table " will display the foreign keys on a table if declared by the developer. I tried to use "show table status on " and expected to see foreign key relationships in the comments column, but it was not the case. Anyway, is there a query i can use to check for foreign key relationships between tables in a schema?
2. What are some of the good queries i can use to perform analysis on database? I have been given an old database that i need to analyze so we can improve on its design and structure.

Thanks.

Comment: Look into the information_schema database you'll find some useful information in the tables there. Including keys.

Comment: If this is for analysis of a database that you inherited, why aren't you using visual tools such as SQLYog or similar? Turn a weeks worth of work into several minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for this:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM  
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE 
  CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY'
```

Possible types of constraint may be:

- `PRIMARY KEY` for primary keys
- `FOREIGN KEY` for foreign keys
- `UNIQUE` for unique constraints

So you're interested in `FOREIGN KEY` type. This will show you which table on which column has the constraint, but won't show you targeted constraint column and table. To find them, you need to use another table, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` which has such information, so, basically, to reconstruct relation between tables, you'll need:

```
SELECT 
  t.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
  t.TABLE_NAME, 
  r.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME 
FROM  
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS t 
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS r 
    ON t.CONSTRAINT_NAME=r.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
WHERE 
  t.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY'
```

But that's, again, is missing columns (because it doesn't belongs to those tables) and will show only relations via FK between tables. To reconstruct full relation (i.e. with columns involved) you'll need to refer to `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` table:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_SCHEMA, 
  TABLE_NAME, 
  COLUMN_NAME, 
  REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA, 
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, 
  REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE 
  REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA IS NOT NULL
```

This query will show all relations where referenced entity is not null, and, since it's applicable only in FK case - it's an answer to the question of finding FK relations. It's quite universal, but I've provided methods above since it may be useful to get info about PK or unique constraints too.

Comment: Hi Alma. That is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks everybody too for providing suggestions. One more question, can a database considered to be "relational" if it does not have any foreign key? What are some of the advantages, if any, of having a database without any referential integrity?

Comment: The schema i am taking over has about 1000 tables, and using the queries provided above, the schema does not use any foreign keys. Is this a good design, not using foreign keys or referential integrity? In what situation would this type of design would be idea?

Comment: Well, I suggest you to ask that in separate question - because even if it's related to method of gathering that kind of information, it's fundamental design question